# Visual Studio Code does NOT find all references of Angular variables

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using (Visual Studio) Code Version 1.24.1 on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.5. I am working on a Angular (5) applications and have noticed that the 'Find All References' functionality does not pick up occurrences of variables in the HTML template files. Is there any plugin enabling this?

An example. Let us suppose we have

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

    public myVariable;

}
```

and the template `component.compontent.html` being

```
<div>{{myVariable}}</div>
```

If I right click on `myVariable` and then `Find All References`, the reference in the template will not be found.

Comment: Sorry I just re-read your question. What do you mean HTML References? How do you expect to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I use TypeScript Hero.  https://github.com/buehler/typescript-hero/wiki

or use VS Codes setting: 
    "typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": true,